# Enumeration of points with infinite dimensions

Tags: combinatorics

A well known way to enumerate points with finite support in an infinite dimensions space $N \times N \times ...$ *and avoid duplicates* is to use the exponents of the factorization of $n$ as the coordinates.

E.g.
$1 \to (0,0,0,...)$
$2 \to (1,0,0,...)$
$3 \to (0,1,0,...)$
$4 \to (2,0,0,...)$
...

We can also apply the pairing function multiple times:

Point $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,0,0,0,...)$ is mapped to:

$<..<<x_1,x_2>,x_3>..,x'_n>$ (with the condition that $x'_n = x_n - 1$ to avoid duplicates)

> Are there other well known ways to do such enumeration?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not well know, but I do it by taking the prime factorization of $n$, for example, $$3,628,800 \Rightarrow 2^8 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 7^1;$$ and listing how many of each prime there a are; $${8, 4, 2, 1, 0, 0...};$$ take each number and if it is even, divide by 2, and if it is odd, add 2 and divide by -2; $${4, 2, 1, -1, 0, 0...};$$ these are your dimensions; $$x_1 = 4; x_2 = 2; x_3 = 1; x_4 = -1;$$ also can be expressed as $$4 + 2i + j - k.$$ 
I expanded the function to include all positive real numbers except zero, if $n$ is a positive integer, plug $\text{floor}(n)$ into previous function, and multiply all of the values by $(n-\text{floor}(n))$.

Comment: It's basically the same method.

Comment: in the list of primes, you have $\{8,4,2,1,0,0,...\}$, but when I apply your method of "add 2 and divide by -2" if it is odd, it should not turn the $1$ into the $-1$ that you have in the next step, because $\frac{1+2}{-2}\neq -1$.